# Dataframe to dict python pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, output

I have the following dataframe, imported from a python dict:

`perimeter    risk  vuls
0  External    High    35
1  External     Low     9
2  External  Medium    76
3  Internal    High    36
4  Internal     Low     8
5  Internal  Medium    41`

and I need to extract the following output:

```
data = 
[perimeter:External, risk:{High:35, Low:9, Medium:76}],
[perimeter:Internal: risk:{High:36, Low:8, Medium:41}]
```

What is the best approach to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want a list of dictionaries each of which comes from a single perimeter. You can loop through the grouped data frame with group variable of `perimeter` and construct the `perimeter` from the key and `risk` from the values with a list comprehension as follows:

```
[{'perimeter': k, 'risk': g.set_index('risk').vuls.to_dict()} 
 for k, g in df.groupby('perimeter')]

# [{'perimeter': 'External', 'risk': {'High': 35, 'Low': 9, 'Medium': 76}},
#  {'perimeter': 'Internal', 'risk': {'High': 36, 'Low': 8, 'Medium': 41}}]
```